# Proving $e$ is irrational using its reciprocal and the inequality $0<e^{-1}-s_{2n-1}<\frac{1}{(2n)!}$.

Tags: taylor-expansion, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

Here is a small part of the proof found on Wikipedia:

[image]

I am trying to understand the inequality used for the proof of $e$ being irrational. The inequality is

> $0<e^{-1}-s_{2n-1}<\frac{1}{(2n)!}$

Is the middle part the error of the series for $e^{-1}$ after the $n$th term? Or is it for another term in the series? And what does $\frac{1}{(2n)!}$ siginify? Does it have something to do with the neglected terms after the series is stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results from *Leibniz' criterion* for alternating series: the error for a convergent alternating series when truncated at the $n$-th term is no more than the next term in absolute value, and it has the same sign.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply. I understand now where $\frac{1}{(2n)!}$ comes from!

Comment: May I ask whether the last term in $s_{2k-1}$ is $-\frac{1}{(2k-1)!}$?

Comment: Yes,so the next (non-written) term in the series is $\;\frac{1}{(2k)!}$.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps my understanding. I am not sure whether I should ask this as a new question or ask it here, but later in the proof it says that $(2k-1)!s_{2k-1}$ is always an integer. Is there a proof on here or on a resource website that shows this fact or is it trivial?

Comment: It' trivial, if you think of it: since the denominators are factorials, each of them is a divisor of those that follow, so the lcm of the denominators is the last one.